# Looking to find the last row on my sheet where there is another record of it, then copy and paste data below

Tags: excel, vba

I am in the process of trying to create a Macro so that we can press a button and it updates the whole sheet.

Essentially all my data is being collected from another workbook, but it has to be non macro hence all my data is pulling through to my sheet Do Not Delete.

I have got my Macro to cycle through and copy/paste as values onto another sheet and remove all the rows that contain the text '#VALUE!'.

I have tried searching around on how to do this, but to no avail. I am trying to find out how to search each row on the 'Do Not Delete' sheet for the value that is in Column G on each row for anywhere that this exists elsewhere in the workbook, but I am unable to do this. From the point that I find the last record where it exists, I want to then copy down from there onwards.

```
Sub CopyToSheet()
'
' CopyToSheet Macro

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws, wscopy, wsdnd As Worksheet
Dim i, LastRowa, LastRowd As Long
Dim WSheet As String
Dim SheetName As String

Set wsdnd = Sheets("Do Not Delete")
Set wscopy = Sheets("CopyAndClear")
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macro - Do not delete")

'Finding Sheet to use
SheetName = Range("L2")
Debug.Print Range("L2")

'Clear Contents
wscopy.Activate
wscopy.Cells.Clear

'Activating Do Not Delete Sheet to copy the data
wsdnd.Activate
LastRowa = wsdnd.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
wsdnd.Range("A1:IP" & LastRowa).Select
wsdnd.Range("A1:IP" & LastRowa).Copy

'Copy and paste cells onto new sheet
wscopy.Activate
wscopy.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
'Apply Filter
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
LastRowc = wscopy.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
wscopy.Range("A1:IP" & LastRowc).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="#VALUE!"


'Delete Rows
wscopy.Range("A1:IP" & LastRowc).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete

'Clear Filter
On Error Resume Next
wscopy.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to search through every sheet of `wb` for the value in the G-column in Do Not Delete and copy everything from that line to last line in that sheet but how do you define "the last record"? And where would you paste the data then?

Comment: Hi, Column G will contain a unique value which will also appear in column G of another sheet in the workbook as we have a tracker of e.g. 'Weekly Measure Sheet 03.02.22'. I've realised an issue with this, however. It's a monthly report we send to our suppliers so the a lot just shouldn't be on there from previous months (unless it's a Monday of the new month). Ideally I want to find the last record that was input onto the sheet and then from there it should insert rows on the first empty road of my sheet which you see I find in L2 (I made a formula for this to find the correct sheet)

Comment: Sorry I'm only able to get back to this now, can I still help you out with this or has this been resolved? If you still need help, I'm still unaware how you would define "the last record" or will there only be one sheet containing the value per cell in the G-column of the "Do not Delete" sheet? i.e. G2 is only found in one sheet (that's not "Do not Delete"), G3 is only found in one sheet...